# Comparator reverseOrder understanding in Java8

Tags: java-8

```
Comparator.comparing(SortedClass::getValue)
          .thenComparing((  SortedClass::getKey),reverseOrder());
```

VS

```
Comparator.comparing(SortedClass::getValue)
          .reversed()
          .thenComparing(SortedClass::getKey).reversed();
```

Looking at the second code it seems like final value will be Sort by Value descending then sort by key descending again. But surprisingly both expression giving me the same result. Any explanation why ?

Comment: You sort by key then reverse it, so even if you do that many odd or even times, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to see if you split into two statements.

```
Comparator<SortedClass> comp1 = Comparator.comparing(SortedClass::getValue)
          .reversed()
          .thenComparing(SortedClass::getKey);

Comparator<SortedClass> comp2 = comp1.reversed();
```

`comp1` is "sort by value descending, then by key ascending". So when you reverse that, of course you get "sort by value ascending, then by key descending".

Comment: putting `reversed()` at last will reverse everything in the comparator. anyway i will go with Approach 1 , which is more clean and elegant.